# Mapping Ports with Azure Docker Containers

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, express, containers

Is there a way in Azure to map ports to a Docker container?  I have an image I've build using Node + Express that takes in an environmental variable to determine which port to listen on.  In Azure, using any port over 1024 seems to work fine, but below that the process raises an uncaughtException error.  Obviously I'd like to use port 80 (and 443)  for production.  I'd like to map port 80 to a configured port within my container (e.g. docker run -p 80:3000.  How can I accomplish this within Azure.

The error raised when mapping to port 80 is:

```
server port is 80
{ Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1241:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1306:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1394:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/node/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/dist/app.js:34:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80 }
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Which Azure service do you use? Azure VM or the Azure Container Instance?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is not yet supported, you can vote for this feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/34082284-support-for-port-mapping).

Also, looking at the docs, it appears port 80 should be working just fine (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart) example).

Comment: I also get permission denied errors when I try to start a service on port 80 in an Azure Container Instance. Trial and error showed that the first port number that works is 1024.. all ports below result in permission denied. I think this is a linux problem though, not one of Azure Container Instances? Only root can bind to ports below 1024.

Comment: On Linux the port below 1024 are privileged ports. What you do inside the container needs to run with admin privileges or the port needs to be explicitly permitted. The best way to solve this would be mapping of container port to external port like docker does it, but it seems like az does not yet

Comment: On the request someone claims it was supported now, but I could not find out in whcih version or shell: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances/suggestions/34082284-support-for-port-mapping